# Safari and the z-index flash problem

Tags: flash, safari, z-index

I don't know if it's a classic safari 4 bug, but apparently many people cannot display correctly  a non-flash content (div, image, etc.)  over a flash animation.
I tried everything: The wmode (switching from "opaque" to "transparent"), the z-index and many other div "cheats".

Did anyone know if there is a safari 4 patch/trick/script to fix this problem?

Thank you very much,
regards.

Answer (score 2):

this bug affects only a specific combination of osx, flash plugin and webkit version (so both safari and chrome are affected, in different versions)

Answer (score 1):

Please provide specific version numbers and Mac or Windows (Flash Mac plugin is slightly different than Flash Windows).
Flash 9 + Safari 4 works fine with my company's website and HTML elements z-indexed over flash.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice I got some answers. I can't remember the flash version ... for the rest: it was 10.5.8 and safari 4.

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue here, with both Chrome and Safari on a PC. (Macs work fine)

In my particular case, I have a flash video inside a cross-domain iframe. No matter what z-index scheme I choose, I can't seem to make a div stay on top of the flash video.

Does anyone know where we can report this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix the exact same problem using help I found here: http://vimeo.com/forums/topic:28312

I gave the div that was wrapping the flash element a position:relative, and the object then sat nicely. I didn't do any wmodes or z-index changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with the strobe media player in safari. I changed the option 
wmode=opaque and it is working fine.